# How to randomly distribute data points across rows of sparse matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cell-array

Please consider my sample code:

```
N=256; % some constant
data=randsrc(1,N,[1:.01:5]); % data points
b=[1,2,4,8,16] % no. of blocks where a b represents no. of rows in output matrix
```

How to divide `data` (1x256) into blocks `b=[1,2,4,8,16]` in a random grouping of data indices like this using a `for` loop:

For a single output matrix following are the conditions:

1. Each row randomly picks the data point excluding the data points picked up by other row(s).
2. The rest of the indices in a row have a zero.

Output matrices are as follows:

```
out1= 1xN=same as data(1x256)(no division into blocks)

out2= is a 2xN matrix
      row 1 picks random 128 data points and rest of indices are zero. 
      row 2 picks rest of the 128 data points (excluding data points of row 1)
      and places them at a different index (other than that of row 1).
```

Similarly,

```
out4=  is a 4xN matrix
       Each row uniquely picks random 64 data points

out8=  is 8xN matrix
       and Each row picks 32 random data points 

out16= is a 16xN matrix
       and Each row picks 16 random data points.
```

How can you do this using a `for` loop running over `b=[1,2,4,8,16]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each output matrix has a different number of rows, it is easiest to put them in a cell array of the same length as `b`.

```
out = cell(numel(b),1);
```

The following loop will compute the matrix for each value in `b` (e.g. `[1 2 4 8 16]`).

```
for ii=1:numel(b),
    out{ii} = zeros(b(ii),N);
    partInds = floor((randperm(N)-1)*(b(ii)/N));
    out{ii}(sub2ind([b(ii) N],partInds+1,1:N)) = data;
end
```

For the values `b=[1 2 4 8 16]` and `N=256` in the question, `out` will look like the following:

```
out = 
    [ 1x256 double]
    [ 2x256 double]
    [ 4x256 double]
    [ 8x256 double]
    [16x256 double]
```

Note that you can verify the expected number of non-zeros in each row of matrix `out{ii}` with `sum(out{ii}>0,2)`.

Comment: @chappic:thank you !
I have a similar another question that:
How divide this data into blocks b=[1,2,4,8,16] with same conditions except that now any number of data points (picked up from any index from 1:256) can appear in any number of groups with putting zeros to the locations occupied in other blocks.
I hope i have made it clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
o=zeros(b,numel(data))
r=mod(randperm(256),b)
o(sub2ind([b,N],r,[1:N]))=data
```

Basically i generated a vector `r` which contains the row the data is written to. The rest of the second line is conversion to linear indices.

/updated, now each sizes contains same number of zeros.